# Build QT for 32 bit application on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 (QJSValue: No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-14.04

I donwloaded QT source codes from [this link](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/). Then I configured for 32 bit

```
./configure -platform linux-g++-32
```

Then make to start the build process.
Along the way, I got this error. Wonder somebody can help on this.

```
qmetaobjectpublisher.cpp:44:20: fatal error: QJSValue: No such file or directory
 #include <QJSValue>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Did you see this https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46850 ?

Comment: Which Qt tarball did you download exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build qt from sources from git.

[This is HowTo](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)